# Swift generic method should use overloaded generic function

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

I'm having trouble getting the desired effect with Swift generics. I defined some generic functions, but for specific cases I would like to override them to provide additional features. When I call the functions from a non generic method/function everything works fine (it uses the specific versions when the argument types match and the generic version otherwise), but when I call the functions from a generic method/function it always uses the generic version of the function (never the specific versions).

Here's an example playground:

```
func printSomething <T> (something: T) {
    println("This is using the generic version.")
    println(something)
}

func printSomething(string: String) {
    println("This is using the specific version.")
    println(string)
}

func printSomeMoreThings <T> (something: T) {
    printSomething(something)
}

class TestClass <T> {

    var something: T

    init(something: T) {
        self.something = something
    }

    func printIt() {
        printSomething(self.something)
    }
}

printSomething("a")
println()
printSomeMoreThings("b")

let test = TestClass(something: "c")
println()
test.printIt()
```

This gives the following output:

```
This is using the specific version.
a

This is using the generic version.
b

This is using the generic version.
c
```

I would like it to use the specific version all the time (since it's calling printSomething with a String argument all the time). Is there a way to do this without overloading every method/function with a specific String version. Especially for the Class case, because I can't overload the class methods for specific types of T?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32606334/369489 duplicates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This currently cannot be achieved for reasons that you have mentioned yourself (you can't overload instance/class methods for specific types of `<T>`).

However, instead of using function overloading, you can check the type during runtime and act accordingly:

```
func printSomething<T>(something: T)
{
    if let somestring = something as? String
    {
        println("This is using the specific version.")
        println(somestring)

        return
    }

    println("This is using the generic version.")
    println(something)
}
```

The impact on performance should be negligible unless you call this function thousands of times.

Comment: @RugenHeidbuchel: No problem! Consider filing a bug report at Apple about the issues with overloading.

Comment: @RugenHeidbuchel would you be kind and share with me the "bug report" so I can vouch for it ? I'm very new to all this Apple stuff :) tnx.

Comment: The id of the issue is 20600972, I think you should be able to find it that way...

Comment: @RugenHeidbuchel I'm terribly sorry for this but apparently I can not see the bug that you report due to http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/152760 ... Am i missing something ?!? Again, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @RugenHeidbuchel: You cannot find bug reports other than your own, even if you have the ID. What you were probably thinking of was OpenRadar, where bugs are filed publicly. The ID provided to you by Apple is for referencing a specific bug report that _you_ have made.

Comment: No trouble at all, I'm happy someone else is interested in this annoying bug! It's too bad you can't see the bug... If you want to vouch for it I think the best thing to do is just file a new bug report for it... Mine is closed because they did not find it a bug. (Which is actually true, but there should be a better way of doing it...)

Comment: @VatsalManot Thanks for enlightening me! Do you agree with my last comment? That it's best to file a new bug report?

Comment: @RugenHeidbuchel if your bug report is "closed" then I don't want anything with people at Apple :-) How on earth this is not a bug ?!? In the meanwhile, would you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/32606334/369489 to see if it the same thing as we have here ?

Comment: @RugenHeidbuchel: Actually, after consideration, I don't think it's a bug. Think about it for a second; according to you, are asking the compiler to add extra runtime code to check whether `T` is a `String`, and if it is _then_ use the specific version, creating overhead and negatively impacting the performance. Also, within the scope of the class, you are thinking from a 'generic perspective', so it makes sense that the generic function is always chosen.

Comment: @VatsalManot unfortunately I hail from a country that is not allowed (by Google) to view OpenRadar :(  Thanks for your insight anyways.

Comment: @VatsalManot please see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/32606334/369489 which I beleive captures the essence of this. I might draw your attention to the final part of the question in which I mention what is wrong ,imho, if this is by design.

Comment: @ashy_32bit: Unfortunately that question is a duplicate of this question. I definitely think that it _is_ by design, and a pretty good design at that.

Comment: @VatsalManot "according to you, are asking the compiler to add extra runtime code to check whether T is a String, and if it is then use the specific version", you are , of course, right and this is *the* right thing to do. This is exactly *late (dynamic)* binding as is expected to be done by the compiler when the situation arises.

Comment: @VatsalManot I indeed agree that's it's not a bug... The problem is that there's no elegant (swiftly) solution. I also think you're workaround doesn't work for the class method's case, bu I'll have to check that.

Comment: @RugenHeidbuchel: Here's some intuition that will hopefully help you understand where generic/specific functions are used. Think about your code expression, and ask yourself whether, _at compile time_ you are going to know what type `T` is? And don't just limit yourself to thinking about the compilation of your project, think about it as a module which can be imported in other projects. How will the compiler know what to do outside your module?

Comment: @VatsalManot That's indeed a nice intuition. It's just too bad your workaround is not as swiftly as generics.

Comment: @VatsalManot exactly my point, but from a different angle though you are using it to arrive at the opposite conclusion :) The compiler is supposed to be smart enough to *delay* binding if the situation calls for it. It is like polymorphism. A method name mentioned in a piece of code does not necessarily translate to the exact static type that contains that method, but the compiler actually delays th call until runtime when more type information is available to make a better decision.

Comment: @RugenHeidbuchel: There will unfortunately be no 'swifter' solution unless you rewrite the compiler.

Comment: @ashy_32bit: I disagree. The advantages of the proposed solution seems are outweighed by the disadvantages, in this case, rewriting the compiler. Also, as I said before, in a generic class, you're thinking from a generic perspective. It should be intuitive that a generic function will be used instead of a non generic function.

Comment: @ashy_32bit: Suppose I create a function `printSomething` outside this module, in my own project where I'm importing `TestClass` as a library. Then what is the compiler supposed to do?

Comment: Too much of complications. The whole compilation would be almost non-deterministic to the programmer.

Comment: @VatsalManot perhaps I'm not getting your point but my answer is: the compiler is supposed to gather all it can and then decide what to do. It is not like the compiler does not know about your `printSomething` function when compiling your project. The internals of such things is of course the domain of compiler writers. But perhaps I'm missing something big here :)