# Generic and (early?) binding in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

```
func f<T>(a:T)->String { return "Generic" }
func f(a:Int)->String { return "Integer" }
func alias<T>(a:T)->String { return f(a) }

f(1) // "Integer"
f("string") // "Generic"

alias(1) // "Generic" (shouldn't be "Integer" ?)
alias("string") // "Generic"
```

I understand that some form of early (static) binding is happening but I don't understand why. Is it by design or a bug? if by design then `alias(a) =/= f(a)` but the definition reads exactly `alias(a) = f(a)` !

Comment: possible duplicates with http://stackoverflow.com/q/29717698/369489 ?