# Swift generic method does not use most specific type

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

I have a marker protocol that is applied to a couple types

```
protocol Foobar {}
extension String: Foobar {}
extension Int: Foobar {}
```

I want to define a generic method for this protocol that implements some default behavior, but which I can overload for specific types. This works:

```
func foobar<T: Foobar>(_ t: T) {
    print("default")
}

func foobar(_ t: Int) {
    print("int")
}

foobar("hi.") // default
foobar(3)     // int
```

The problem is if I wrap this in another generic method call

```
func wrapper<U>(_ t: U) where U: Foobar {
    foobar(t)
}

wrapper("hi.") // default
wrapper(3)     // default <---- !!!
```

I had hoped the compiler sees that `Int: Foobar` so `wrapper(3)` is compiled with `U == Int` (i.e. the most specific type) and thus the behavior is the same as `foobar(3)`. However it seems that instead `U == Foobar`.

Is there a different way to write this such that `wrapper(3)` does the same thing as `foobar(3)`? I know I could perform runtime type-checking inside it to force the same behavior but it seems to me like the compiler should be able to figure it out.

---

As pointed out in the comments, I could just specialize `wrapper`:

```
func wrapper(_ t: Int) { foobar(t) }
```

that works, but imagine I have a bunch of other types that also conform to `Foobar` and have their own overloads. Now I have to write

```
func wrapper(_ t: Int)    { foobar(t) }
func wrapper(_ t: Double) { foobar(t) }
func wrapper(_ t: String) { foobar(t) }
func wrapper(_ t: Bool)   { foobar(t) }
// ...
```

with code like that I would hope I could use generics to avoid the repetition

Comment: You are passing an object that conforms to Foobar not an integer. Totally expected.

Comment: Is there a different way to write this such that wrapper(3) does the same thing as foobar(3)?  yes you have to write a wrapper method that takes an Int `func wrapper(_ t: Int){ foobar(t) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus In my actual application there are many types that conform to `Foobar` and many specific overloads for them. I could write a specific wrapper method for each one, but each wrapper would look completely identical other than the parameter type. I thought generics were specifically designed to avoid such boilerplate code

Comment: There is no way to accomplish what you are asking AFAIK. an object that conforms to Foo has no relation with an Int

Comment: Leo's points are spot-on, but also the key point is that generics are generally determined at compile time. That's their intent. But more importantly, generic overloads must only every improve performance. If they change behavior, you're doing something wrong. If `f(x)` does something visibly different when `x` is an Int versus when `x` is "something that is like an Int," then you're abusing overloads. This is the wrong tool (and probably the wrong way of thinking, even if the tool supported it).

Comment: I expect, however, for a *concrete* problem, this is very solvable. It only becomes a mess when you try to solve it in a general way unconnected to any actual problem. (This is very common when dealing with Swift generics and protocols.)

Comment: @RobNapier i have a very concrete problem in a production app, but it is huge and under NDA. This is the smallest example I could come up with.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717698/swift-generic-method-should-use-overloaded-generic-function

Answer (score 2):

The comments convinced me that my desired solution is impossible, so I came up with a different approach that achieves similar functionality without code duplication.

The first thing to notice is that the various `foobar` methods really have no relation in Swift. Because their parameter types are different, they are treated like completely different methods despite having the same name. So might as well not even try to make them look the same

```
func foobarDefault<T: Foobar>(_ t: T) {
    print("default")
}

func foobarInt(_ t: Int) {
    print("int")
}
```

Now the problem becomes more clear: you have totally different methods, how does `wrapper` know which one to call for its argument? Easy: put the information in the protocol!

```
protocol Foobar {
    static var foobar: (Self) -> Void { get }
}
// default implementation
extension Foobar {
    static var foobar: (Self) -> Void { return foobarDefault }
}
// conformance
extension String: Foobar {}
extension Int: Foobar { static let foobar = foobarInt }
```

The wrapper implementation is trivial

```
func wrapper<U: Foobar>(_ t: U) {
    U.foobar(t)
}
```

This does exactly what I want, the only difference is you specify the foobar overload alongside the protocol conformance, which is even nicer now that I think about it. In my case I even decided to leave out the default extension so that it would be more explicit how each type is implementing the protocol!

---

As Jessy pointed out that is a very silly example. In my actual application the `foobar` methods are more complicated. It's more like

```
struct Validator {
  // has some internal data determining how it validates things
  let blah = ...

  // knows how to validate everything based on its own data
  func validateDefault<T: Foobar>(_ t: T) -> Bool { ... }
  func validateInt(_ t: Int) -> Bool { ... }
}
```

Because the validators are constructed dynamically at runtime, the wrapper needs a validator injected `wrapper(foobar, validator)`. So how do you set it up here? I chose to do it like this

```
protocol Foobar {
  static var validate: (Validator) -> (Self) -> Bool
}
extension Int: Foobar {
  static let validate = Validator.validateInt // so simple!
}

func wrapper<U: Foobar>(_ t: U, _ validator: Validator) -> Bool {
    return U.foobar(validator)(t)
}
```

Yeah, you could do it with instance methods instead, but it kinda sucks:

```
protocol Foobar {
  func validate(_ validator: Validator) -> Bool
}
extension Int: Foobar { // this is the part that gets repeated for every type!
  func validate(_ validator: Validator) -> Bool {
    return validator.validateInt(self)
  }
} // much noisier

func wrapper<U: Foobar>(_ t: U, _ validator: Validator) -> Bool {
    return t.foobar(validator)
}
```

Comment: An instance `() -> Void` is the same thing as a static `(Self) -> () -> Void`. You need to figure out if these are static methods or instance methods. I put the instance version in my answer, but your examples are static.

Comment: @Jessy see my updated answer, the context is much more complicated than `() -> Void` methods. I'm very curious if you still see a much simpler way to do things

Comment: No, that's looking good! But…
1. There's no need for your "Hungarian notation", e.g. `validateInt`. You don't need that for disambiguation. Just use `Validator.validate` for all of them, as you were doing.
2. The Swift signature for a `validate` return is `throws -> Void`, not `-> Bool`. Switch to the modern (2015) standard!
3. You can extend `Foobar` to have the instance method, instead of repeating it. Do that if you need it outside of `wrapper`.

Comment: I edited my answer again to ask why you're even bothering with the protocol, though. It looks useless other than being a marker for the default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As you've shown, overloading `wrapper` is the way to do it, abstracting to inherited protocols of `Foobar`, or composite protocols, when possible. The alternative, as taken by [_print_unlocked](https://oleb.net/2018/dont-call-description/), is to use "runtime type-checking", as you also mentioned. Overloading takes the best possible advantage of the type system.

You should use code generation (e.g. [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery)) for this. The language should have a native mechanism, yes, but it's not there yet.

You haven't demonstrated, in your answer, that the protocol is doing anything for you, other than providing a default, for some types. You're just moving overload code into a protocol. Why? Either option is a use case for code gen.

```swift
struct Validator {
  func validate(_ validatable: Validatable) throws {
    print("default")
  }

  func validate(_ int: Int) throws {
    print("int")
  }
}
```

```swift
protocol Validatable { }
extension String: Validatable { }
```

```swift
func wrapper<Validatable: ModuleName.Validatable>(
  _ validatable: Validatable, _ validator: Validator
) throws {
  try validator.validate(validatable)
}

func wrapper(_ int: Int, _ validator: Validator) throws {
  try validator.validate(int)
}
```